# Javascript alert with all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push, alert

How do i send a single alert with all objects? Everytime i tried it will came out undefined or [object, object]

```
var array  =[];


function object ( name, username, password)
this.name = name
this.user = username
this.pwd  = password

var object1 = new object ("jack","jacky","123") 
var object2 = new object ("bob", "bobby", "qwe")

array.push(object1);
array.push(object2);

alert () //What to put??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [];

function object(name, username, password) {
  return {
    name: name,
    user: username,
    pwd: password,
  }
}

var object1 = new object("jack", "jacky", "123") 
var object2 = new object("bob", "bobby", "qwe")

array.push(object1, object2);
```

then either this:

```
var message = 'array'.concat(':', ' ', JSON.stringify(array, null, 2))
alert(message) 
/*
array: [
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "user": "jacky",
    "pwd": "123",
  },
  {
    "name": "bob",
    "user": "bobby",
    "pwd": "qwe",
  }
]
*/
```

or this...

```
array.forEach((arrayItem) => {
  var message = 'object'.concat(':', ' ', JSON.stringify(arrayItem, null, 2))
  alert(message)
})

/*
object:   {
  "name": "jack",
  "user": "jacky",
  "pwd": "123",
}
*/
/*
object: {
  "name": "bob",
  "user": "bobby",
  "pwd": "qwe",
}
*/
```

or this...

```
var message = array.reduce((_message, arrayItem) => {
  var _objectMessage = 'object'.concat(':', ' ', JSON.stringfiy(arrayItem, null, 2), '\n')
  _message = _message.concat(_objectMessage)
  return _message
}, ''}
alert(message)
/*
object:   {
  "name": "jack",
  "user": "jacky",
  "pwd": "123",
}
object: {
  "name": "bob",
  "user": "bobby",
  "pwd": "qwe",
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to make a loop with `array` item:

```js
var array  =[];


function object ( name, username, password) {
  this.name = name
  this.user = username
  this.pwd  = password
}

var object1 = new object ("jack","jacky","123") 
var object2 = new object ("bob", "bobby", "qwe")

array.push(object1);
array.push(object2);

array.forEach(function (item) {
  alert("name: " + item.name + ", user: " + item.user + ", pwd: " + item.pwd);
});
```

---

Or if you want to display all of the values with just one message, you can try this:

```js
var array  =[];


function object ( name, username, password) {
  this.name = name
  this.user = username
  this.pwd  = password
}

var object1 = new object ("jack","jacky","123") 
var object2 = new object ("bob", "bobby", "qwe")

array.push(object1);
array.push(object2);

var message = "";

array.forEach(function (item, index) {
  message += "object" + (index + 1) + ": name: " + item.name 
          + ", user: " + item.user + ", pwd: " + item.pwd + "\n";
});

alert(message);
```

Comment: almost! i just need all that in one single alert. i tried alert (item.name,item.user,item.pwd) but it keeps sending multiple alerts with each object instead of one single alert